# Iterating over arrays and extracting data from JSON file

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

Here is a JSON that I'm receiving from the server

[Doubt.JSON](http://pastebin.com/3WSSmCBa)

My question is here I'm receiving two "imageData" which is of type Array. How do I extract each one of those and assign them to let's say collection view cells. As in 1st imageData should go to one cell and next so on.

I'm using ALAMOFIRE and SWIFTYJSON. If anybody could help me out using/ not using SwiftyJSON, I'd really appreciate it.

My JSON:

```
{
  "response" : {
    "start" : 0,
    "docs" : [
      {
        "enrollmentId" : [
          "2534534246"
        ],
        "fieldName2" : [
          "Languages"
        ],
        "locality" : [
          "XYZ"
        ],
        "active" : [
          true
        ],
        "sex" : [
          "Male"
        ],
        "latitude" : [
          1.2340
        ],
        "city" : [
          "udya"
        ],
        "imageData" : [
          "data:image\/png;base64,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"
        ],
        "fieldValue2" : [
          "English, Hindi, Kannada"
        ],
        "fieldValue1" : [
          "11 years"
        ],
        "state" : [
          "Karnataka"
        ],
        "id" : "Iuusofijpw",
        "email" : [
          "cont@dontcare.com"
        ],
        "longitude" : [
          12.4352
        ],
        "firstName" : [
          "Praqwer"
        ],
        "_version_" : 1521637513434759168,
        "experience" : [
          10
        ],
        "caseTypes" : [
          "A Particular caseType let's say Bheema",

        ],
        "lastName" : [
          "Bsdtty"
        ],
        "mode" : [
          "Lawyer"
        ],
        "fieldName1" : [
          "Experience"
        ]
      },
      {
        "state" : [
          "Karnataka"
        ],
        "languages" : [
          "English",
          "Hindi",
          "Kannada"
        ],
        "lastName" : [
          "KWE"
        ],
        "firstName" : [
          "RANDARTY"
        ],
        "sex" : [
          "Male"
        ],
        "caseTypes" : [
          "Bheema",

        ],
        "enrollmentId" : [
          "4253646"
        ],
        "mobile" : [
          42534346
        ],
        "id" : "Iurweoin",
        "imageData" : [
          "data:image\/png;base64,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"
        ],
        "active" : [
          true
        ],
        "mode" : [
          "Kelsa"
        ],
        "city" : [
          "Udya"
        ],
        "_version_" : 15216,
        "email" : [
          "Him@somenone.com"
        ],
        "experience" : [
          18223
        ],
        "locality" : [
          "XYZ"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "numFound" : 2
  },
  "responseHeader" : {
    "status" : 0,
    "QTime" : 5,
    "params" : {
      "q" : "mode:(\"Lawyer\", \"CA\") AND active:true AND city:(\"Bereello\") AND locality:(\"XYZ\") AND caseTypes:(\"Momerty\")",
      "wt" : "json"
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url!)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON{ response1 in
        switch response1.result{
        case .Success:
            let json33 = JSON(data: response1.data!)

            print(json33)
            if let userDict = json33["response"].dictionary{

                if let array = userDict["docs"]?.array{

                    for imgd in array{

                        let me:String! = imgd["imageData"][0].string

                        let url = NSURL(string: me)!
                        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                        let imgView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
                        self.view.addSubview(imgView)
                    }


                }

            }
```

Comment: There's *many* similar questions and answers on this site. Have a look. Do it step by step: learn how to extract your values from the JSON. Then learn how to make an image from the value. Then learn how to make table views. Then learn how to assign your images to cells. Good luck! We'll help if needed.

Comment: Hello @EricD, [MyCode](http://pastebin.com/EXMjJWaj). This is what I've been doing and I'm getting proper results too. But I am unable to figure out when I get multiple "imageData" arrays. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of your dictionaries has one entry for the image text, and these dictionaries are in an array.

I would use `flatMap` to quickly get these image strings:

```
let allImageStrings = json["response"]["docs"].flatMap { $0.1["imageData"].first?.1 }
```

Explanation: we iterate over `json["response"]["docs"]` and we access the second part of the tuple (remember, a SwiftyJSON object always has `(index, value)`) and from there we take the second part of the first tuple inside ["imageData"].

It looks complex like that but when you look at the JSON structure it's actually rather clear.

Comment: I'm getting it. But there's just one problem. I'm getting both the strings AS ONE BIGG string. How do I separate the two according to who's image it actually is?

Comment: If you use my example you will get one array containing the two strings, not one big string.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I got one array containing two strings. How do I separate the two after getting? Because I'll have to assign each of them to collection view cells. :(

Comment: Lifesaver. Thank you so much! Will get back when I start getting problems assigning them to collection view cells.

Comment: Ah! You're welcome. ;) Yes, don't hesitate to post a new question about it if you're stuck.